# Calling Razor Pages method via ajax not working

Tags: razor-pages

I'm trying to call a Razor Pages method from ajax but it ends up just calling the OnGet() method of the page. The url seems right as it's

```
https://localhost:7100/?handler=SearchCityState&cityTerm=Det
```

The method I want to call is in the Index.cshtml.cs file and the name is correct. It's defined as:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchCityState(string cityTerm){
 ...
}
```

If I put that url in the browser it goes to my OnGet() method instead. Am I missing some configuration or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix handler names with `OnGet` or `OnPost`, otherwise they are just any method as far as Razor Pages is concerned:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSearchCityState(string cityTerm){
 ...
}
```

Comment: So that worked. Follow-up question. If I put Async at the end of the method name and put that in the ajax call it doesn't work. Am I messing with another convention there by doing that?

Comment: Adding Async to the name should have no effect at all. It should still work. It's an optional suffix which is ignored when the default handler selection convention looks for matches on HTTP method and name: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods